# What is font in TeX?

Tags: fonts

I am reading "The TeXbook" chapter4, which is about font. I feel the author did a really good job illustrating font in TeX. However, when I tried to explore more by myself, I feel so confused like I never know font. It is like a font has so many attributes distributed in different directories. Anyway, how should I learn font and the way TeX deal with font?

Comment: Have you, please, a screenshot?

Comment: @Sebastiano You've misunderstood the question, I think. This is not about identifying a font, but about how the TeX primitive `\font` and related commands work as described in the TeXBook.

Comment: In all honesty, especially if you are going to be a LaTeX user, learning about how the original  TeX handles fonts may not be worth the effort. There is some more explanation to be found in [TeX by Topic](http://texdoc.net/pkg/texbytopic) which might be helpful.

Comment: Some related questions on the site that might be helpful: [Looking for an “easy to understand” description of the tfm file format](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/115099), [Where are the math font parameters?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/318483). For a description of the different font file extensions and what they mean see https://tug.org/tds/tds.pdf.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank you so much for your feedback. You've noticed that on several occasions I don't understand the question. I was thinking something different. Best regards.